# How to checked/uncheck checkboxs across all the page at pagination when click on a first page select all checkbox

Tags: php

For Ex. I have a data table with 5 pages using pagination .Every page has a select all  checkbox button in header and every rows has one check box at first column of table  .if I  click on first page select all checkbox then all checkbox across the pages should be check or unchecked .Also all checkbox value should be post.

Comment: you have to provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overview of a check-all scenario. It's hard to say if is the type of thing you are looking for though based on your question:

**Form**

```
<label><span id="check_all">Check All</span><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /></label>
<label>Check 1<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem" /></label>
<label>Check 2<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem" /></label>
<label>Check 3<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem" /></label>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){  
    var IsChecked = $('#checkAll').prop('checked');
    if (IsChecked == true) {
        $('.checkItem').prop('checked',true);
        $('#check_all').html("Clear All?");
    }
    else {
        $('.checkItem').prop('checked',false);
        $('#check_all').html("Check All");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yarr15e3/